# Workflow for sending Email Template with updated Account and Opportunity

Tags: email, workflow, email-template, opportunity, account

I am updating my opportunity(Child object) and Account(Parent Object) through API. I want to send updated fields to selected email addresses to email templates. I was trying the workflow criteria as:

Opportunity Name contains "Value" and evaluate criteria as

"created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria"

I have defined the email addresses in the additional email section but the emails are not sending through to the email addresses.

Is their any mistake that I am doing in the process?

Thank you

Comment: when you update the value?is the new value is different from old value?I am asking this just to investigate if the criteria is fulfilled to fire the workflow; refer to http://www.stratushub.com/blog-content/salesforce/salesforce-101-understanding-workflow-rule-evaluation

Answer (score 0):

There is a common misconception with workflow trigger criteria of `created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria`

The key here is `edited to subsequently meet criteria` which really means that before the update, the record didn't meet the criteria.

For example, if a workflow rule should fire when amount > 10, and the Opportunity is created with amount = 5, then updated to amount = 15 and then updated again to amount = 20, the workflow fires only once (when amount = 15). It won;t fire again until the amount is changed to something <=10, then changed again to something > 10.

If you are using a filter of `Opportunity Name contains "Value"`, then before the API update, the Opportunity Name must not contain the string `"Value"`

A couple of other things to check:

1. Your API update of the Opportunity actually succeeds without any exception
2. You are not simulating the API via a testmethod - email messages will never be sent in testmethods.
3. Look in the debug log in the workflow trace - you can see what values are passed to the workflow rule from the SObject Opportunity. Perhaps you have additional conditions in the workflow rule that prevent rule execution